# Some axios.get requests fail with "Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

so I'm using Nodejs and have an express route, that looks like this:

```
app.get('/approvedmr/:id', async (req, res) => {    
    try {
        const projectid = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
        const apMR = await new MergeRequestApproval().getResponse(projectid, 'Any');
        res.send(await new MergeRequestApproval().getHeader(apMR, 'Any'));
    } catch {
        res.sendStatus(404);
    }
});
```

and this is the `getResponse` function:

```
    async getResponse(id: number, approval: string) {
        const axiosInstance = axios.create();
        return await axiosInstance.get(`gitlaburl/api/v4/projects/${id}/merge_requests?approved_by_ids=${approval}&per_page=1`, defaultheader);
        }
```

I've omitted some parts in the `getResponse` as they only check if the the approval-String contains a certain string.

Now. Locally everything works fine, once I deploy a dockerized version of this to a test server, those ids work for [1;99], if the id is greater than that, say, 100 or 330, it will return an error like so:

This is the error.stack:

```
"Error: Request failed with status code 404\n    
at createError (/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    
at settle (/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)\n    
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:205:15)\n    
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1154:12)\n    
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)"
```

I initially used `axios.get` instead of `axios.create().get` but then read that that could cause the issue, however it did not.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot per se identify a problem. Most likely the `MergeRequestApproval().getHeader` function is throwing an unresolved error. Another reason could be that you in fact don't have a project with an higher id than `99`
However I think you could restructure parts of your code. I would take `getResponse` which is returning gitlab's Response (as an axios response) and forward the response without mutation in your express server.

```
app.get('/approvedmr/:id', async (req, res) => {    
    const projectid = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
    const apMR = await new MergeRequestApproval().getResponse(projectid, 'Any');
    res.json(apMR);
});
```

ApMR includes the response [data and header](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) of your **HTTP request**.
*Note, that I used `res.json` for convenience. `res.send` is as good but not including response headers for the content type `JSON`.*

If you want to explicitly return an 404 in case no item was found you can stick to [axios's error response status](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors).
e.g.

`res.sendStatus(apMR.response.status);`

Stitching it all together you could structure your endpoint like this:

```
app.get('/approvedmr/:id', async (req, res) => {   
    try { 
        const projectid = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
        const apMR = await new MergeRequestApproval().getResponse(projectid, 'Any');
        res.json(apMR);
    catch (e) {
         if (e.response) {
             res.sendStatus(apMR.response.status);
         }
         // You might want to extend your error handling here.
         // what about service outage (of gitlabs API), network issues, invalide auth etc.
    }
});
```